# Who makes the throw for the duration of a dispel on item?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, traps

I read that a way to bypass a magical trap is by doing a dispel on it.
If it succeds, it is affected like an item :

> If the object that you target is a magic item, you make a dispel check
>   against the item’s caster level (DC = 11 + the item’s caster level).
>   If you succeed, all the item’s magical properties are suppressed for
>   1d4 rounds, after which the item recovers its magical properties.

**Who is supposed to make the 1d4 throw for the suppression effect duration ? The one doing the dispel ? or the GM ?**

Answer (score 6):

### It doesn't matter, it's just a die roll...

But technically speaking, it's the function of a creature's spellcast, so the default person to roll it is the player that controls that creature (similar to how you would typically roll your own Fireball's damage dice). This also reduces the GM workload, since they have up to a dozen or more creatures to maintain and roll for.

That being said, the GM is the arbiter of the rules and can claim responsibility for *any rolls they wish*. For instance, if the GM doesn't want the PC to know when they're 'safe', that's within their purview. The GM should make it clear who's rolling when the spell is cast, if there's any question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the answer to my question depends too much on how you master the game, therefore I should not have asked, it's too opinion dependent...
Should I close it ?

Comment: @Binochio it is generally opinion based, but you can leave it up and the community will decide if it doesn't qualify. There is a distinction to be made in-game whether the players know the results of the action. It's a completely valid question in that light.

Comment: This is still a valid question even though the answer is "It's up to your GM," see https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7353/does-ask-the-dm-gm-equate-to-primarily-opinion-based